# Tensorflow cannot find DLL, but DLL directory is in PATH

Tags: windows, tensorflow, keras, dll, dependency-management

I am running a Python file inside a virtualenv. This Python file imports keras, which imports tensorflow. Running the file gives this error:

```
(mnist) C:\Users\user1\Documents\GitHub\misc-python\mnist\src>python process_data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 60, in preload_check
    % " or ".join(missing))
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

However msvcp140_1.dll exists in a directory which is in my PATH:

```
(mnist) C:\Users\user1\Documents\GitHub\misc-python\mnist\src>where msvcp140_1.dll
C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\Scripts\msvcp140_1.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140_1.dll
```

```
(mnist) C:\Users\user1\Documents\GitHub\misc-python\mnist\src>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\user1\Envs\mnist\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;...
```

This is what is installed in my virtualenv:

```
(mnist) C:\Users\user1\Documents\GitHub\misc-python\mnist\src>pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
-ensorflow             2.2.0
absl-py                0.9.0
astunparse             1.6.3
bleach                 1.5.0
cachetools             4.1.1
certifi                2020.6.20
chardet                3.0.4
cycler                 0.10.0
gast                   0.3.3
google-auth            1.19.2
google-auth-oauthlib   0.4.1
google-pasta           0.2.0
grpcio                 1.30.0
h5py                   2.10.0
html5lib               0.9999999
idna                   2.10
importlib-metadata     1.7.0
Keras                  2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
kiwisolver             1.2.0
Markdown               3.2.2
matplotlib             3.3.0
numpy                  1.19.0
oauthlib               3.1.0
opt-einsum             3.2.1
Pillow                 7.2.0
pip                    20.1.1
protobuf               3.12.2
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules         0.2.8
pyparsing              2.4.7
python-dateutil        2.8.1
PyYAML                 5.3.1
requests               2.24.0
requests-oauthlib      1.3.0
rsa                    4.6
scipy                  1.4.1
setuptools             49.2.0
six                    1.15.0
tensorboard            2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.7.0
tensorflow             2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator   2.2.0
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1
termcolor              1.1.0
urllib3                1.25.9
Werkzeug               1.0.1
wheel                  0.34.2
wrapt                  1.12.1
zipp                   3.1.0
```

I am using Windows and I have tried rebooting. How can I get tensorflow to find this DLL?

Comment: If you're running x86 32-bit Python, then you need an x86 32-bit build of msvcp140_1.dll. Try installing [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe).

Comment: The advice to use `PATH` is outdated for Python 3.8+. `ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name)` no longer uses `PATH`. Instead the directory where the DLL is located has to be in the application directory (e.g. `sys.prefix`), the "Sytem32" directory, or specifically added to the current process DLL search path via [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory). If the tensorflow project wants to continue using the legacy search that uses `PATH`, they need to override the call as `ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name, winmode=0)` in 3.8+.

Comment: @ErykSun I should have mentioned, I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Can you start tensorflow with out python? The vc_redist arch should be the same with tensorflow.

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows 10, anaconda 4.9.2, after installing tensorflow 2.3, python 3.8 on conda,
the same problem occurred, so I solved it via modifying ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name) to ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name, winmode=0) in self_check.py.

Comment: first time in a long while, I have logged into Stackoverflow, to share my thanks. This is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens to someone else: Just go to 'this pc' in the explorer and search for `msvcp140_1.dll`.
Many python packages like PIL as well as other software come with this dll, so you likely already have a copy it on your computer, even without installing the "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" (which would require admin rights you might not have).

Just copy the path of any folder containing it and issue

```py
import os
os.add_dll_directory("some/path/containing/the/dll/")
```

before

```py
import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing tensorflow via conda, instead of pip.