# Tensorflow on miniconda with python 3.8. msvcp140_1.dll missing

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, miniconda

EDIT:
I solved it with help of this thread and the comment by Eryk Sun. I added winmode=0 in self_check.py. Dont know if it was best solution, but it worked :)
[Tensorflow cannot find DLL, but DLL directory is in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62971631/4232738)

> The advice to use PATH is outdated for Python 3.8+. ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name) no longer uses PATH. Instead the directory where the DLL is located has to be in the application directory (e.g. sys.prefix), the "Sytem32" directory, or specifically added to the current process DLL search path via os.add_dll_directory. If the tensorflow project wants to continue using the legacy search that uses PATH, they need to override the call as ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name, winmode=0) in 3.8+. – Eryk Sun Jul 18 '20 at 18:19

Im using Miniconda and have followed the instructions for installing tensorflow with
`conda create -n tf tensorflow`

Im then using the tf interpreter in VS Code.

But i still i get the below error.

> Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these
> DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

I have reinstalled the x64 redistributable three times, but the error is not solved.

The file is present in the following paths
C:\Users\myusername\miniconda3\envs\tf\msvcp140_1.dll
C:\Users\myusername\miniconda3\envs\tf\Library\bin\msvcp140_1.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140_1.dll
C:\Users\myusername\miniconda3\Library\bin\msvcp140_1.dll
C:\Users\myusername\miniconda3\msvcp140_1.dll

I have read all threads and pages i can find about this issue, but for most its solved when installing the redistributable, but that doesnt work for me.

I dont know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to follow the instructions you have listed i.e. under the tensorflow library located under your environment in the directory `site-packages` you will notice a file called `self_check.py` modify the line shown below in this module to include `winmode=0`

```
  for dll_name in build_info.build_info[MSVCP_DLL_NAMES].split(","):
    try:
      ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name,winmode=0)
```